# Different select statements based on row values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that contains two different GPS device types. I am needing to create a single query that filters based on the GPS device type.

The (gl200) device type query would look like this:

```
SELECT t1.deviceid, t1.devicetime, t1.latitude, t1.longitude
FROM positions t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(id) as LatestGpsPoint
    FROM positions
        WHERE deviceid IN
            (SELECT deviceid FROM device_group WHERE groupid = 7)
            AND valid = 1
            AND attributes LIKE '%FRI%'
            AND network != 'null'
            AND devicetime >= (SELECT deploymentdate 
                              FROM devices
                              WHERE id = deviceid
                              LIMIT 1
            )
            GROUP BY deviceid
    ) t2
ON t1.id = t2.LatestGpsPoint
ORDER BY t1.deviceid ASC
LIMIT 0,100
```

The other device type (dmt) query would look like this:

```
SELECT t1.deviceid, t1.devicetime, t1.latitude, t1.longitude
FROM positions t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(id) as LatestGpsPoint
    FROM positions
        WHERE deviceid IN
            (SELECT deviceid FROM device_group WHERE groupid = 7)
            AND valid = 1
            AND devicetime >= (SELECT deploymentdate 
                              FROM devices
                              WHERE id = deviceid
                              LIMIT 1
            )
            GROUP BY deviceid
    ) t2
ON t1.id = t2.LatestGpsPoint
ORDER BY t1.deviceid ASC
LIMIT 0,100
```

I'm trying to put an IF ELSE END statement in there to change the search criteria based on t1.protocol = 'gl200' or 'dmt'.

Answer (score 0):

Try UNION:

```
(SELECT t1.deviceid, t1.devicetime, t1.latitude, t1.longitude
FROM positions t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(id) as LatestGpsPoint
    FROM positions
        WHERE deviceid IN
            (SELECT deviceid FROM device_group WHERE groupid = 7)
            AND valid = 1
            AND attributes LIKE '%FRI%'
            AND network != 'null'
            AND devicetime >= (SELECT deploymentdate 
                              FROM devices
                              WHERE id = deviceid
                              LIMIT 1
            )
            GROUP BY deviceid
    ) t2
ON t1.id = t2.LatestGpsPoint)
UNION
(SELECT t1.deviceid, t1.devicetime, t1.latitude, t1.longitude
FROM positions t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(id) as LatestGpsPoint
    FROM positions
        WHERE deviceid IN
            (SELECT deviceid FROM device_group WHERE groupid = 7)
            AND valid = 1
            AND devicetime >= (SELECT deploymentdate 
                              FROM devices
                              WHERE id = deviceid
                              LIMIT 1
            )
            GROUP BY deviceid
    ) t2
ON t1.id = t2.LatestGpsPoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

An if statement is a possibility but I think you might be able to do it with a case statement. The only difference in the code is this part:

```
    ...
    AND attributes LIKE '%FRI%'
    AND network != 'null'
    ...
```

Which only applies for the 1st query, the GL200 device.

The case statement would start after `AND valid = 1`.

```
SELECT t1.deviceid, t1.devicetime, t1.latitude, t1.longitude
FROM positions t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(id) as LatestGpsPoint
    FROM positions
        WHERE deviceid IN
            (SELECT deviceid FROM device_group WHERE groupid = 7)
            AND valid = 1
            AND CASE WHEN deviceID = 'gl200' --however you id the device
                      THEN attributes LIKE '%FRI%' --gl200
                      ELSE 1=1  --dmt
                END

            AND CASE WHEN deviceID = 'gl200' --however you id the device
                      THEN network != 'null' --gl200
                      ELSE 1=1 --dmt
                END
            AND devicetime >= (SELECT deploymentdate 
                              FROM devices
                              WHERE id = deviceid
                              LIMIT 1
            )
            GROUP BY deviceid
    ) t2
ON t1.id = t2.LatestGpsPoint
ORDER BY t1.deviceid ASC
LIMIT 0,100
```